# Applying style from QGIS to OpenLayers VectorLayer?

Tags: openlayers, style

I have a vectorlayer exported from QGIS and added to an openlayers map. I now want to style this layer according to the style I use in QGIS. It consists of numerous line features and they should be styled according to an attribute. Since I want to apply a lot of different styles it would be a ton of work to write those styles manually.

Is there a better workflow than manually adding the styles to the layer?

I thought about applying a .sld to the layer, but openlayers does not seem to support this. I know it is possible to add the .sld to a Layer in Geoserver, but Geoserver is not an option for me here.

I use Openlayers version 5.3.

Comment: You could try using https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nieuwlandgeo/sldreader or alternatively convert to a mapbox style and then convert that to an OpenLayers style https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35830350/how-to-style-layers-with-sld-in-ol3

Comment: The sldreader seems like a good way to accomplish it. But even though I installed it, I struggle to make it run. I added the `applySLD` function to my javascript code, but I do not understand how to refer to my vectorlayer or my .sld file. Could you explain that? Would be great

Comment: I've not used it but take a look at the live examples and their sources and you should be able to replicate that with your data https://nieuwlandgeo.github.io/SLDReader/index.html https://nieuwlandgeo.github.io/SLDReader/assets/ol.js
https://nieuwlandgeo.github.io/SLDReader/grenzen.html https://nieuwlandgeo.github.io/SLDReader/assets/grenzen.js
https://nieuwlandgeo.github.io/SLDReader/benelux.html https://nieuwlandgeo.github.io/SLDReader/assets/benelux.js

Comment: Since the purpose of GIS SE is to compile a list of answers that will last a long time, stating that you use "the latest version" is of little real value.  Please [Edit] the question to include the actual version in use.